# Extract one whole column from DataTable without using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, .net-2.0

I have a `DataTable` with many columns in it. I want to extract the entire 3rd column it in, and put the values in a string array. And I do NOT want to use LINQ as I'm using .net 2.0 Framework, which by default does not support LINQ.

So how can I do this without LINQ ?

Comment: Show us any code you have written or have tried to solve this issue yourself?

Comment: use foreach loop then

Comment: Azhar I am trying to use the `Select` statement to do filtering, but as far as I can tell, it can only filter rows, not columns ...

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] result = new string[datatable.Rows.Count];
int index = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    result[index] = row[2].ToString();
    ++index;
}
```

Comment: That is a very obvious case of solving this. Can't I use a one line statement somehow, such as use `Select` in some manner ?

Comment: And the `Select` method on `DataTable` actually is a `Where`, not a `Select`. It only allows you to filter the rows. It doesn't allow you to select the columns to return.

Comment: Nope, `Select` is not LINQ. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.80).aspx .. Yeah I kind of knew that too, but figured that maybe there is a syntax for it to select speific column values or something.

Comment: @Ahmad: No, there is no syntax. The documentation is pretty explicit on this: "Gets an array of all **DataRow** objects that match the filter criteria"

Comment: "That is a very obvious case of solving this" - what's wrong with obvious?